# How to get rid of Nonetype in the python list

Tags: python, list

```
a = [-0.0003445, 7.21e-05, 7.53e-05, -0.000159874, -4.56e-05, 0.000182252, -0.000281612, 0.000420009, -0.000102176, 1.77e-06, 0.000480935, 0.000248943, 0.000111458, 0.000144402, -0.000337367, -0.000286356, -1.16e-05, -8.93e-05, 7.6e-05, 6.61e-05, -7.63e-05, -0.000120216, 0.000137981, -0.000329544, -1.27e-05, 1.15e-05, 2.97e-05, -0.000341322, 1.422174931, -0.00013796, '', '', '', '', ]
```

What is the most effective way to delete 'NoneType' values from the list and get back the list without them?

I could do this stupid way but would like to know better way.

```
new_a = []
for i in a:
   if i is not 'NoneType':
       new_a.append(i)
```

Comment: `[ elem for elem in a if bool(elem) ]`

Comment: That list does not contain `None`s. What are you seeing that suggests otherwise? Do you mean empty strings? The simple way though is `b = [x for x in a if x is not None]`.

Comment: `b = list(filter(None, a))`, if it was actual `None`s…

Comment: @bracco23: Explicit conversion to `bool` is unnecessary, unpythonic, and (surprisingly) slow. It also doesn't properly eliminate only `None`s, but anything that's falsy (e.g. `0`, `0.0`, `[]`, etc.).

Comment: @deceze: That removes falsy values, not just `None`, to be clear. `filter(None` is equivalent to `filter(bool`. That said, they have no `None`s, just empty strings, so maybe it's what they want?

Comment: For the time being, I think this question should be closed until it's clarified. The answers are all over the place because the question is quite unclear.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I added the explicit conversion just to make it clearer what was happening (slower, really?). But good point on the falsy value, empty list or strings might not be a problem but 0s might definitely be

Comment: @bracco23: Yeah, slower. I've had real code that actually ran 30% slower overall because of an unnecessary conversion of a maybe-empty `list` to `bool` rather than just using implicit truthiness evaluation (in fairness, it was *the* ridiculously hot code path; not a common case); `bool` invokes both generic function call machinery and generic constructor machinery all to ultimately invoke a very cheap `PyObject_IsTrue` check (which gets redone when the `if` actually uses it); the overhead relative to the real work done is greater than just about anything else in CPython. Surprising, but true.

Answer (score 1):

Using list comprehensions:

```
new_a = [item for item in a if item is not None]
```

This creates a new list and only adds each item in the list a if its value is not None

https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension

Comment: Thanks, it works.

Comment: "only adds each item in the list a if its value is not None" is not a fully accurate statement. `if item` will exclude anything with a falsely value, including `None`, `False`, `0`, empty `str`, etc

Comment: @Wondercricket True, I've updated to specify, which is important especially for an list of numbers

Comment: You should compare `None` with `is` always.

Answer (score -1):

A list comprehension is the idiomatic way of doing this:

```
new_a = [i for i in a if i is not 'NoneType']
```

Comment: `is not 'NoneType'` should not be anything you ever find yourself writing…

Comment: @deceze: The OP explicitly said that comparing against the string `'NoneType'` would work.

Comment: Comparing strings with `is` is never guaranteed to work.

Comment: @deceze: That's fair